# Steam whitelist checker for CS 1.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, steam

I wrote some code that reads the output of the `rcon users` command on the CS 1.6 console. It then notifies me of any players that are not in my whitelist.csv or are in my blacklist. The program requires 3 files as inputs:

1. A text file containing the raw output of the `rcon users` command on CS 1.6 console.
2. A CSV file containing the SteamID and name of the white-listed players.
3. A CSV file containing the SteamID and name of the black-listed players.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import csv
import re


class WhiteListVerifier:
    """
    Class to check if non-white-listed players are playing CS.
    """
    def __init__(self, users_filepath, whitelist_filepath, blacklist_filepath):
        """
        Get filepaths and load the following files: users file , whitelist file and blacklist file

        users_filepath: Path to a text file which contains the raw output of the 'rcon users' in the in-game console.
        whitelist_filepath: Path to a csv file which contains Steam IDs and player-names of the white-listed players.
        blacklist_filepath: Path to a csv file which contains Steam IDs, player-names and alert-message for the black-listed players.
        """
        with open(users_filepath) as f:
            self.users_rawcontents = f.read()
        self.whitelist = list(csv.DictReader(open(whitelist_filepath)))
        self.blacklist = list(csv.DictReader(open(blacklist_filepath)))

    def get_playername(self, steamid, player_records):
        """
        Function to return name of a person if steamid exits in given records 
        and return 'Unknown' otherwise.
        """
        for player in player_records:
            if steamid == player['Steam_ID']:
                return player['Player_Name']
        return 'Unknown'

    def get_active_users_steamids(self):
        """
        Function to extract the Steam IDs using output of 'rcon users' command.
        """
        active_users_steamids = re.findall(r'STEAM_[0-5]:[01]:\d+', self.users_rawcontents)
        return active_users_steamids

    def verify_steamids(self):
        """
        Function to alert if people other than the ones mentioned in the whitelist are playing.
        """
        active_users_steamids = self.get_active_users_steamids()
        num_nonwhitelisted_users = 0

        for active_user in active_users_steamids:
            player = self.get_playername(active_user, self.whitelist)
            if player is 'Unknown':
                num_nonwhitelisted_users += 1
                nonwhitelisted_playername = self.get_playername(active_user, self.blacklist)
                print('-- nonwhitelisted player: '+str(nonwhitelisted_playername))
        print('>> Total number of non-whitelisted players: '+str(num_nonwhitelisted_users))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    checker = WhiteListVerifier('data/users.txt', 'data/whitelist.csv', 'data/blacklist.csv')
    checker.verify_steamids()
```

Comment: Why is there both a blacklist and whitelist? What does it mean for a player to neither be on the whitelist nor blacklist?

Comment: Whitelist is for people with whom I play regularly. Blacklist is for people that I don't want to play with. And if I see a new id which is neither on my whitelist or blacklist, I'll ask them if I know them personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but is essentially O(N**2); you can make it O(N) fairly easily by turning your whitelist/blacklist into dicts:

```
def __init__(self, users_filepath, whitelist_filepath, blacklist_filepath):
    """
    Get filepaths and load the following files: users file , whitelist file and blacklist file

    users_filepath: Path to a text file which contains the raw output of the 'rcon users' in the in-game console.
    whitelist_filepath: Path to a csv file which contains Steam IDs and player-names of the white-listed players.
    blacklist_filepath: Path to a csv file which contains Steam IDs, player-names and alert-message for the black-listed players.
    """
    with open(users_filepath) as f:
        self.users_rawcontents = f.read()
    raw_whitelist = list(csv.DictReader(open(whitelist_filepath)))
    raw_blacklist = list(csv.DictReader(open(blacklist_filepath)))
    self.whitelist = { p['Steam_ID']: p for p in raw_whitelist }
    self.blacklist = { p['Steam_ID']: p for p in raw_blacklist }

def get_playername(self, steamid, player_records):
    """
    Function to return name of a person if steamid exits in given records 
    and return 'Unknown' otherwise.
    """
    return player_records.get(steamid, 'Unknown')
```

So instead of iterating over the entire list of player_records every time you look someone up, it iterates over your whitelist and blacklist each *once* at startup-time, making them thereafter be O(1) to search by steamid (which is the only kind of search you ever do).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really should have thought about using hash maps instead of iterating over a list over and over to find something. Again, thanks! I appreciate it.